# What does "they blew everyone away" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

> The band was awesome! They blew everyone away.

What does this mean? Surely it does not mean the band actually blew everyone away. But it seems to mean something good?

Comment: Interesting side note: Particularly in American English "blowing something away" can mean shooting or exploding it. Hence "When that criminal shot at the policeman, the police blew him away" means that the police overwhelmingly defeated (and killed) the criminal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Free Dictionary, in its [article for *to blow*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blow) has the following definitions:

> *blow away* Slang
>   2. To defeat decisively.
>   3. To affect intensely; overwhelm: *That concert blew me away.*

I guess, it's exactly the meaning you need.

Answer (score 10):

It means something good; in fact, *blow [someone] away* [means](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blow_away) *leave [someone] greatly impressed*.

Do note that there are quite a few other meanings for this expression (it might mean *kill someone by gunshot* or *get rid of*, for example).